# What is the best preposition to describe things inside a boat?

Tags: word-choice

I'm translating a story into English. A fisherman had some things inside his small boat.

Those things are like a knife, a plate to eat, fishing net, money, tools,..etc.

Now, I don't know how to say this sentence:

> The boat crashed into an Island. Everything that was (inside/on/in)
>   the boat (fell/drown) in (sea/water/seawater).

The words in the brackets came to my mind but I can't choose the correct one.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For boats, the idiomatic preposition is *on* or *on board*.

> As the ship ran aground on the jagged rocks, everything that was **on board** flew into the water, including the hapless sailors.

You can talk about items that are *in* a particular part of the boat, though:

> The delicate astrolabe that had been **in the captain's cabin** smashed through the stern windows and shattered on the rocks below.

You can also use *at* to describe objects that were at a particular place on the boat:

> The elaborately carved mermaid figurehead **at the bow** of the ship snapped off, but otherwise escaped unscathed.

Side note:  In case you are unfamiliar, in English, there are different terms for the directions on a nautical vessel.  To the right is **starboard**, to the left is **port**, to the back of the ship is **aft**, and the front **fore**.  The front part of the ship is called the **bow**, and the rear the **stern**.

[There are many other terms, if you are curious.](http://www.boatsafe.com/nauticalknowhow/gloss.htm)

Comment: I think you've given some sound advice here. That said, I can't find anything wrong with: _Everything that was **in** the boat was lost._